# Set ACL for USB Device (Token) at Windows

Tags: windows, usb, acl, token

How can I set ACL for USB device (token)? 
Need to set access control for USB-token at 1 PC (for example):
**Enable:**
- 1-st user can use the 1-st token;
- 2-nd user can use the 2-nd token;

**Disable:**
- 1-st user can't use the 2-nd token;
- 2-nd user can use the 1-st token.

Maybe somebody has:
- links;
- literature;
- code samples (any language).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10042/The-Windows-Access-Control-Model-Part-1) a very good serie about ACL with many samples in C++ and C#.

Comment: As you correctly hint, USB devices are represented by tokens. You can apply this ACL knowledge on these objects either (as with any Windows named object).